# Determine types of input, output and internal variables in compiled functions

Tags: compile, complex

I am trying to speedup the computation of a longer function using `Compile`. For illustration consider the following short example:

```
procTest = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
    res = Log[-x];
    Im[res]
];
```

The input and output are both real valued. But Mathematica `Compile` seems to assume that this means that it can use the real `Log` function inside the routine. At least the following commands

```
procTest[-1.]
procTest[1.]
```

output reads

```
0
CompiledFunction::cfse:  Compiled expression 0. + 3.14159 I should be a machine-size real number.
CompiledFunction::cfex:  Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 2; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
3.141592653589793
```

Of course I can change the type `_Real` to `_Complex` which makes this example work, but the output is then a complex quantity with zero imaginary part. Is there a way to tell `Compile` that it should assume real input and outputs, but complex quantities can appear inside the function? If not, can I convert the output type from complex to real? I am worried about the output type because it seems to confuse other parts of my computation (not sure, but probably `FindRoot` tries to perform a complex root search if the arguments are not reals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the type-inferencer of `Compile`. Here is one way around this:

```
procTest =
  Compile[{{x, _Real}},
     Module[{res = 0 * I},
       res = -x;
       res = Log[res];
       Im[res]]];
```

In which case, both test cases work all right.

Comment: Of course, the intermediate variable `res` should be localized in a `Module` anyway. By incorporating `res=0*I`, you're essentially declaring `res` to be `Complex`. Is that correct? If so, I would have expected `0.0*I` to make more sense. I guess that `Module` has the attribute `HoldAll` so that it sees the `I` anyway.

Comment: @MarkMcClure My guess is that the type-inferencer inside `Compile` introspects internal `Module` anyway, and has its own means to determine the type, so I did not feel it necessary to use `0.0 * I` - but in general you are probably right, `0.0 I` should be safer.