# Creating a multidimensional array with Compile

Tags: compile

For one of my programs I need to preallocate a multidimensional list/array. For performance reasons I want to do this within `Compile` and compile my program to C-code.

Now I made the following observation for the following minimal working example:

```
cf = Compile[{}, Block[{list},
    list = Table[{0., 1.}, {1}, {1}];
    list[[1, 1, 2]]], CompilationTarget :> "MVM"];
```

with `CompilationTarget :> "MVM"` this function works just fine. When I call `cf[]` I obtain the expected result `1.`. Now if I change `CompilationTarget->"C"`, I receive the following error message when I define the function `cf` in MMA

```
CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::cmperr: Compile error: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\ApplicationData\CCompilerDriver\BuildFolder\compiledFunction100.c(152) : error C2440: 'function' : cannot convert from 'mreal' to 'MTensor *' >>
Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function. >>
```

Note that for both `CompilationTarget`s `CompilePrint` shows that the code just compiles nicely.

If I keep the code to be compiled to `C` but change the dimensionality of the `list` the error message disappears

```
(*Compiled function*)
cf = Compile[{}, Block[{list},
    list = Table[{0., 1.}, {1}];
    list[[1, 1]]], CompilationTarget :> "C"];
```

Any clue how this behaviour comes about? I guess the C-compiler cannot handle these kind of `Table`s where I give a `List` of rank 1 as a first argument and only accepts arguments of rank 0. However, since the error message only appears when I define the function but not when I call it, is it safe to use anyway? (since `CompilePrint` shows no call to `MainEvaluate`).

Comment: I would do something like `cf=
With[{list =Table[{0.,1.},{1},{1}]},
Compile[{},
list[[1,1,2]],CompilationTarget:>"C"]]`

Comment: This behavior exists since _v8.0_, not sure if this should be called a bug or a limitation, but I think it's worth reporting to WRI.

Comment: @MichaelE2: In your code you missed the third argument of `list`, i.e. when going down to the single element e.g. by `list[[1,1,2]]`. With `list[[1,1]]` everything works just fine I agree.

Comment: No problem. I think it is not a major issue, since some easy workaround exists. It was more an observation by myself which I wanted to share. And interesting that it seemed to work with older versions of MMA.

Comment: Note if integers are used, I get no error but the kernel crashes on execution of `cf[]`: `cf = Compile[{}, Block[{list}, list = Table[{0, 1}, {1}, {1}]; list[[1, 1, 2]]], CompilationTarget :> "C"]`

Comment: Yes, I observe the same behaviour. `Compile` is sometimes really picky about the arguments of the MMA functions that can be compiled. Sometimes this can cost a lot of time when debugging longer code. Maybe I should just stick to plain C instead.

Answer (score 4):

> …since the error message only appears when I define the function but not when I call it, is it safe to use anyway?

This depends on how you define *safe*. A `CompiledFunction` that's compiled to *C* succesfully owns a `LibraryFunction` as its last argument:

```
Compile[{}, 1, CompilationTarget -> C] // InputForm
```

> `CompiledFunction[……,`**`LibraryFunction[……]`**`]`

This is what makes the `CompiledFunction` faster (in some cases). So, the `cf` will still give you the correct output, but it loses the blessing of *C*.

Finally, a possible workaround:

```
cffixed = Unevaluated@Compile[{}, Block[{list = {{{}}}}, list = Table[{0., 1.}, {1}, {1}];
     list[[1, 1, 2]]], CompilationTarget -> C] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement
```

The keypoint is `list = {{{}}}` i.e. initializing `list` with an empty list with correct dimension. `` Part -> Compile`GetElement `` isn't necessary but it speeds up the code.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. I also like @Rolf Mertig 's comment.

Comment: @DisplayName To get an array of integers, you need to be explicit about the type in the dummy initialization of `list`: `Compile[{}, Block[{list = {{{0}}}}, list = Table[{0, 1}, {1}, {1}];
  list[[1, 1, 2]]], CompilationTarget -> "C"]` -- By default, the type of the empty `list` will be assumed to be depth-3 array of type `Real`. Similar type-inferencing problems are discussed here: [(845)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/845), [(43580)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43580)

Comment: Good to know, thank you!